# Is there a race condition using msw with jest?

Tags: jestjs, msw

I'm worried about race conditions w.r.t. MSW when multiple Jest test files run concurrently.  Is that an issue?

[The MSW getting started guide](https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/integrate/node) suggests the following code in setupTests.js:

```js
// Reset any request handlers that we may add during the tests,
// so they don't affect other tests.
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers())
```

But what if two tests run concurrently, and each starts with something like:

```
server.use(rest.get('https://api.backend.dev/user', (req, res, ctx) => {
  return res(ctx.json({ firstName: 'Paul' }))
})),
```

or

```
server.use(rest.get('https://api.backend.dev/user', (req, res, ctx) => {
  return res(ctx.json({ firstName: 'Ringo' }))
})),
```

Couldn't the handler set up in one test be called by the other test (or vice-versa)?

Do I need to use [--runinband](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#--runinband)?

PS: Maybe I'm misunderstanding Jest because it seems like the "mock dom" implemented by [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) would have the same issues with concurrently running tests.

Answer (score 2):

I've at least convinced myself there's no race condition based on two facts:

1. Each Jest test file runs in its own subprocess.  (This is mentioned in [#5623](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5623#issuecomment-367123517) among other places.). So each test file should have its own `server` instance.
2. MSW on Node just monkey-patches functions like `fetch()` and `XMLHttpRequest`, rather than actually starting a web server.  This is mentioned in [#407](https://github.com/mswjs/msw/issues/407#issuecomment-717798648).  So, the monkey-patching should be isolated to each process running each test file.